# Show browser list when opening a link in android

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, android-webview

I want to open some links in an external browser. Before opening, I want to display the list of browsers on the device. I did this functionality using Intent.ACTION_VIEW. But as per my app's requirement, I want to display the list of browsers even if there is only one browser application on the device. Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have one browser application , the chooser will not launched , the URL will be loaded on that browser application. If you have two or more browser applications, the android system launch an `IntentChooser` the show the list of all browser apps installed on the device , so the user can choose his preferred browser to load the URL :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT :** 
to create your custom Intent Chooser :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));

// Always use string resources for UI text. This says something like "Share this photo with"
String title = getString(R.string.chooser_title);
// Create and start the chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
startActivity(chooser);
```

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my requirement is that I want to display the IntentChooser even if there is only one browser application in the android device. Please advice.

Comment: @MithunRaj you can create you own `IntentChooser` and retreive all browser apps in your device ( in this case it will be one application ), and then display it , see my edits

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.maidofknowledge.com"));
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Choose Your Browser");
            if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(chooser);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

settings>apps>clear default (

this is if you have previously set "use as default app" for chrome

these 2 images are my source:

Message to select browser or select default:
http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/how-to-default-app-03.jpg

Clear default browser, show intent chooser again:
http://cdn2.ubergizmo.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/how-to-default-app-02.jpg